# Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to select the first 2000 rows of a dataframe if the `groupby` count of the particular column is greater than 2000. How can this be done in python? Is the below one is the correct way of doing

```
X_train[ 1:2000, X_train.groupby(['value']).count() > 2000].
```

I am getting `Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`

Please help me in selecting 2000 rows if particular column group by count exceeds 2000.

Comment: This is a standard `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

```
df        = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, 100).reshape((20,5))) 


col       = 0
lower_bnd = 2
n_rows    = 3

count     = df.groupby([col]).size()
selection = count[count > lower_bnd].index
dg        = df.loc[df[col].isin(selection)].iloc[:n_rows]
```

Comment: I want to maintain other rows which does not exceed this groupby count. Suppose if df[col] has 1,2,3 as values , df.groupby['col'].count() of 2 alone exceeds low_bound , then I want to apply this cond only to column having value as 2. other rows should be maintained for the column having other values.how this can be done?

Comment: Can you build a working example and specify the output you are looking for ?